# How Cubic works in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

The `Curves.easeIn` is a `Cubic(0.42, 0.00, 1.00, 1.00)`. If you read the documentation, [it says](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Cubic/a.html):

> The line through the point (0, 0) and the first control point is tangent to the curve at the point (0, 0).

So, the first control point is `(0.42, 0.00)` however, in the curve, I don't see anything starting from this point. So, can anyone explain what that `0.42` is doing in the curve?

From [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Curves/easeIn-constant.html)

[image: From here]

Comment: check https://cubic-bezier.com/#.42,0,.72,1 - first control point is that pink dot

Comment: @pskink Sir, thank you very much, I got :-)

Comment: @pskink thanks! I think this should be framed as the correct answer.